# I am trying to calculate occupancy rate of an apartment during the year, per month, on Google Sheets,

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I have a table with all the reservations for an apartment for 2 years. However, there are reservations that the check in is in a month, and the check-out is the next month.

| Check in | Check out |
| --- | --- |
| 28.01.22 | 03.02.22 |
| 23.03.22 | 01.04.22 |

I did a pivot table, for the number of nights per month, and ordered by check in date, and grouped by month and year.

I figured a way to calculate the number of nights for the respective month. The thing is, I cannot add or subtract the days at the pivot table.

Is there a better way to do it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: In the formula below I made an effort to seperate  calculation steps into variables so you can better understand.  For example if you change the formula so that it outputs `arr` you will get a list of all the days that are booked.

Answer (score 0):

This formula can be adapted to your needs.

```
=LET(in,A:A, out,B:B, start,A2, mos,12,
  labels,MAP(SEQUENCE(mos), LAMBDA(s,
    EDATE(EOMONTH(start,-2)+1,s))),  
  arr,TOCOL(MAP(in, out, LAMBDA(i,o, 
    IFERROR(SEQUENCE(1,o-i,i)))),1),
  MAP(labels, LAMBDA(l, {l, IFERROR(1/(1/COUNT(
      FILTER(arr, YEAR(arr)=YEAR(l), 
        MONTH(arr)=MONTH(l)))))})))
```

Specify the following for the formula:

- the check `in` and check `out` date columns;
- the `start` date whose month will be used;
- the number of `months` to include;

I've got to pop out but will add more detail later.

[image]